# WCF with Sharp architecture - The needed dependency of type could not be located with the ServiceLocator

Tags: wcf, nhibernate, sharp-architecture

I'm working with an application which uses wcf and sharp architecture, I'm trying to create a service to write to the database. Here is my service: (Sicaf.Core.Services.Wcf)

```cs
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFacturaWcfService : ICloseableAndAbortable
{           
    [OperationContract]
    string ConsultarValorMatricula(string xmlData);
}
```

```cs
    [ServiceBehavior, AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class FacturaWcfService : IFacturaWcfService
    {
        private readonly IFacturaBusiness facturaBusiness;

        public FacturaWcfService(IFacturaBusiness facturaBusiness)
        {
            this.facturaBusiness = facturaBusiness;
        }

        public string ConsultarValorMatricula()
        {
            return facturaBusiness.GetFactura();
        }

        public void Abort() { }

        public void Close() { }
    }
```

In the ComponentRegistrar.cs: (Sicaf.Core.Services.WebServices)

```cs
private static void AddWcfServicesTo(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            // Since the TerritoriesService.svc must be associated with a concrete class,
            // we must register the concrete implementation here as the service            
            container.AddComponent("facturaWcfService", typeof(FacturaWcfService));
        }
```

I created a client but I get this exception:

```cs
The needed dependency of type FacturaWcfService could not be located with the ServiceLocator. You'll need to register it with the Common Service Locator (CSL) via your IoC's CSL adapter.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found my mistake.

Before:

```
 private static void AddCustomRepositoriesTo(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            // Register Data Layer Services
            container.Register(
                AllTypes.Pick()
                .FromAssemblyNamed("Sicaf.Core.Services.Data")
                .WithService.FirstNonGenericCoreInterface("Sicaf.Core.Services.Services.Data"));                   
        }
```

After:

```
 private static void AddCustomRepositoriesTo(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            // Register Data Layer Services
            container.Register(
                AllTypes.Pick()
                .FromAssemblyNamed("Sicaf.Core.Services.Data")
                .WithService.FirstNonGenericCoreInterface("Sicaf.Core.Services.Services.Data"));

            container.Register(
                AllTypes.Pick()
                .FromAssemblyNamed("SismatV2.Data")
                .WithService.FirstNonGenericCoreInterface("SismatV2.Services.Data"));
        }
```